# Linux. Как вывести количество установленных соединений на сервере с разбивкой по определенным портам?

Tags: linux

Linux. Как вывести количество установленных соединений на сервере с разбивкой по определенным портам?

Пример:
Порт; текущее кол-во соединений

Answer (score 2):

`ss` - Socket Statistics.

Пример - количество_соединений порт:

```
ss -tuna | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f2 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: скажите, а зачем в программе для интерпретатора awk вы выводите первое поле? ведь следующей в конвейере командой его значение удаляется.